# How to use an activity diagram to detail classes & methods?

Tags: algorithm, uml, modeling

I wish to document code for a fairly complex algorithm whose implementation is intertwined across several methods and classes. A sequence diagram cannot really describe the detail of each method well so I am looking at an activity diagram; however this doesn't typically seem to represent classes and methods, only the logic.

Is there a common or even proper way to show which methods the logic belongs to? I do not need to follow strict UML, the purpose is simply to make it clear what's happening visually.

Comment: Who says you can only use one diagram? Just use a combination of sequence diagrams, class diagrams and activity diagrams and whatever else makes it more clear. If the tool supports it, you can create an overview diagram, that collects diagrams relevant for the question at hand. Adding textual comments is also a good way to guide the reader.

Answer (score 1):

### Activity diagrams and partitions

The **activity diagram** are supposed to models activities without necessarily relating them to classes/objects. They are however very suitable for modeling complex algorithms, as they allows to show :

- the control flow -- flowchart diagrams have proven effective for modeling alorthims; activity diagrams are much more precise in their semantic and can do this as well.
- object flows that show what objects are passed through
- there are object actions that are specifically meant for dealing with objects

Activity diagrams support [**partitions**](https://sparxsystems.com/resources/gallery/diagrams/software/sw-activity_diagram_with_partitions.html), i.e. visual grouping of activities according to a criteria.  A popular use is to split actions by using  subsystems as grouping criteria.  Breaking down by classes seems overkill, but nothing forbids such groupings if it helps, and if you're able to use it consistently.

### Interaction overview diagrams

> Interaction Overview Diagrams are specialization of Activity Diagrams that represent Interactions.

Interaction overview diagrams are a kind of combination of activity and sequence diagrams. The general idea is to use some activity modeling features for showing the big picture of the flows, between interaction nodes, i.e. mini sequence diagrams embedded in the larger diagram, to show which objects are involved and what messages they exchange.

There is an inspiring [**example here**](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/guide/uml-unified-modeling-language/what-is-interaction-overview-diagram/). But be careful: the linked website is based on a former version of UML and the text is not fully up-to-date. The most accurate source on these diagrams is section 17.10 of the UML 2.5.1 specs.

### Additional thoughts

Instead of trying to show everything in one diagram, you may prefer the beauty of simplicity: use an easy to understand, simpler overview diagram, and uncover the complexity in additional diagrams that focus on details.  This works with activity diagram complements with more detailed activities or sequence diagrams.  But it also works the other way round, showing exchanges between key objects in a sequence diagram, and provide more detailed activity diagrams to describe what happens inside of one of the invoked operation.

***Disclaimer**: While I provide some hints that you can use to model algorithms in relation with their classes,  I have at the same time to warn you that [visual programming](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Using-UML-as-Visual-Programming-Language-K%C3%B6hler-Nickel/5a90bab621d6d81092817ca66f113191f33869e1), i.e. a very very very detailed modeling, may lead to very complex diagrams that are difficult to read, and even more difficult to maintain. They loose the benefit of communicating the big picture. I'm not alone in this criticism, see [Grady Booch](https://twitter.com/grady_booch/status/1388930413280727042) who knows what he is talking about, since he is one of the co-inventor of UML,  [Martin Fowler](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/UmlAsProgrammingLanguage.html), and many others*

Comment: The VP page you reference ecplicitely refers to UML 2.0. That's just a bit outdated (though the part they use still seem to be the same in 2.5).

Comment: @qwerty_so thank you for the warning: good to know. I am not used to these diagrams, so I verified in the UML 2.5.1 specs that they still existed before answering. Moreover, this may be one of the few cases where they could be really useful.  The VP page seemed to best convey the potential.  The Sparx, Wikipedia, and uml-diagrams.org examples seemed more basic.

Comment: It made me wonder how many answers here on SO lurke around that still refer to older UML versions (and have lots of up-votes). I seem to remember some about aggregation.

Comment: @qwerty_so indeed, if we look for example at the question and answers on association vs aggregation vs composition where the accepted answer has hundreds of upvote but is just plain wrong in view of the current specs… But let‘s not despair and continue eagerly to spread the  word and encourage good practice ;-)

Comment: There is a problem with the Visual Paradigm page on the Interaction Overview Diagram: They reference the Activity meta model, which really has **nothing** to do with Interaction Overview Diagrams. These diagrams are a visualization of an _Interaction_ and have the _same_ meta model as sequence diagrams. Almost all tool vendors misunderstood the specification. I can see why, though.

Comment: @AxelScheithauer  I've edited,  to draw the attention on the unreliable info in the VP link, and to reinforce my message about keeping it simple by combining several diagrams.

Comment: There's a silver lining: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405302/introducing-outdated-answers-project

Comment: @qwerty_so this is very good news!